# How to create "sub-channels" in Slack to track individual ideas spun off from the main channel?

Tags: slack, channel

We have a Slack workspace within a small (~400) scientific community who are discussing multiple ideas (to help solve the current COVID-19 crisis, so lots of conversations and topics. :-)  Currently using one channel and wouldn't want to create 50.

What's the best way to spin off discussions into sub-topics.  Slack doesn't support sub-channels (yet) does it?
Would a task management plug-in to Slack help here? Want to separate and localize topics and discussions, not track individual responsibility, so "task management" might not be the right paradigm.
Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Slack doesn't have sub-channels but you can mimic by using some conventions.

Eg.

1. `#covid-19-symptoms -> All discussions related to symptoms
2. `#covid-19-symptoms-respiration -> Symptoms related to respiration
3. `#covid-19-symptoms-respiration-topic-3 -> Symptoms related to respiration

If you using this Slack workspace exclusively for discussing Covid-19 you may remove the covid prefix which may be redundant.

You need to have one moderator who can review all the messages, repost/remove/shift across channels to make them more relevant.

Comment: why not separate tags that could be mixed/matched as needed and organized post-ex, eg #covid, #symptoms (so can search #symptoms #monkeypox also)